# autowire Predis Interface in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, predis

i wanna use ClientInterface in my class constructor and i give an error :

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Service\DelayReportService": argument "$client" of method "__construct()" references interface "Predis\ClientInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?
```

seems to be i should add it manually to services.yml i added it like :

```
Predis\ClientInterface: '@Predis\Client'
```

and now i give this error:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "Predis\Client".
```

what is the solution and why symfony itself dont handle it?

Comment: `Predis\ClientInterface` and `Predis\Client\ClientInterface` are not the same thing.

Comment: @Andy yes it is correct i edited question thanks . now i give error `You have requested a non-existent service "Predis\Client".`

Comment: @Andy any idea my friend?

Comment: It appears `Predis\Client` does not exist as a service, so you can't create an alias to it. You'll need to define it as a service.

Comment: @Andy why? could you please giving me an explanation about that? i defined it as public: true and it works now . but i dont know why

Comment: @sina By default Symfony only autowire's stuff under the src directory.  You can see the config that controls this in config/services.yaml.  Hence the need to manually wire your Predis services.  You should not need public:true as long as you are injecting it.  What you probably want to do is to search for a Predis bundle.  A bundle is basically a Symfony wrapper for libraries and will typically define services for you.  Just make sure the bundles is being actively maintained.

Comment: be sure to accept the answer or elaborate what is still holding you back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be confused about how to define a service... which isn't surprising tbh

look here

https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/service_container.html#explicitly-configuring-services-and-arguments

for example

```
    services:
        App\Service\Concerns\IDevJobService:
          class: App\Tests\Service\TestDevJobService
          autowire: true
          public: true
```

where

`IDevJobService` is an INTERFACE
and

`TestDevJobService`
is the actual implementation that will be auto injected

using `@` inside the yaml files is done to reference a service that has already been defined ELSEWHERE

https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/service_container.html#service-parameters

you probably want to watch symfonycasts services tutorial (I am not affiliated and I havent watched it myself yet (sure wish I did)).

**EDIT**
`Predis\Client` is a 3rd party class. It isn't in your `App` namespace or in your `src` folder. Symfony checks the `src` folder for class that it will then make to a service. See `services.yaml` there is a comment there, look for exclude and resource. And I'm not sure, even if you autoload it, that you can then just do `@Predis\Client` to reference an existing service.

be sure as well to debug your config using

`php bin/console debug:autowiring`

under linux you could do as well `php bin/console debug:autowiring | grep Predis` to find it more quickly (if it is there at all)

Comment: why it cant detect Predis\Client as service so i have to add it manually?